# Displaying Token Field Labels From Fetched Entity In Rules HTML Email

Tags: 7, entities, rules, tokens, display-suite

I am sending a MIME HTML email using rules.  Much of the information contained in the email comes from a fetched custom entity (custom ECK entity).  Using the available replacement patterns, I can get the fields from the entity I need to print. However, I'm wanting both the label and the value from the field to display in the email.

I have the Token view mode active for this particular bundle, and the field name visible inline, but in the email, nothing but the value appears.

Hard-coding the label isn't really an option, as I'm dealing with about 15 fields, which will not always be completed in every entity, and I don't want an empty label to show.

How can I get the label to display as well?

Specs/Versions: D7.43, Rules 2.9, Token 1.6, DS 2.13